# Как отловить имя кнопки при клике в компоненте React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В компоненте есть такая кнопка:

```
<a href="#" className="controls-header-left"
                                        name="previous_year"
                                        onClick={this.previousControlClick}>
                                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left" aria-hidden="true">
                                </span>
                            </a>
```

Эта кнопка будет пролистывать календарь на год назад. Также есть кнопка, которая будет переводить год 1 вперед. Тоже самое хочу сделать с месяцами и создать 2 универсальных метода, которые в зависимости от имени кнопки будут листать месяц и год. В общем виде схема такова-метод получает имя, исходя из имени проходит в нужный `case`, далее дергает родительский метод, в который передает, что изменилось. В родительском методе происходит `setState`. При клике `event.target.name` является `undefined`. Соответственно дальше ничего не меняется. Подскажите пожалуйста почему так происходит и как это исправить

Метод на данный момент такой:

```
previousControlClick(event) {

        switch(event.target.name) {
            case 'previous_year' : {
              var changed_year = {'year': this.props.year-1}
              this.props.updateCalendar(changed_year)
            }
            case 'previous_month' : {

            }
        }
    }
```

setState родителя:

```
updateCalendar(param) {

        if(param.year !== 'undefined'){
            this.setState({
                year: param.year
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                year: param.month
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: а пробовали использовать currentTarget ? А вообще кажется у вас происходит ошибка при использовании "всплытия" т.к. фактически вы нажимаете на span , а имя есть только у элемента "a". Вот тут можно почитать как решить такую ошибку https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling. Если я прав, то добавив имя у элемента span ваш код сработает. Хотя это может быть и не так т.к. у вас вызывается функция и вроде бы она уже должна была вызываться для "a" элемента.

Comment: @alexoander проблема была не в том,что я не дал name спанке. currentTarget помог.большое спасибо!есть две просьбы: 1продублируйте пожалуйста комментарий в ответ,чтобы я его выбрал и закрыл вопрос.2можете в 2 словах объяснить в чем разница между target и currentTarget?заранее спасибо

Comment: а чо бы не onClick = {this.previousControlClick.bind(this, 'previous_year')} то есть пробрасывать в обработчик не event а сразу осмысленную строчку. Конечно если у вас name дополнительной нагрузки какой-то не несет

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму отличный вариант.большое спасибо за подсказку.избавился от лишних строк кода.name я ввел только для клика.поэтому можно от него отойти

Comment: @Iga, тут вроде как есть подводный камень что bind обертка будет пересоздаваться при каждом рендере. И в очень-очень больших и сложных приложениях это может вроде как плохо влиять на производительность. Но в большинстве случаев так норм писать.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму то есть для крупно-масштабных приложений лучше будет этот хендлер забиндить в конструкторе как я написал в коде?

Comment: @Iga, а черт его знает если честно. Я с приложениями где это начинает прямо играть значительную роль не сталкивался)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму идею понял) пока в этом маленьком проекте-песочнице данный момент не будет критичным,но на будущее учту

Comment: @Iga, оно и в больших проектах не критично я бы сказал, если внутри рендера не биндить что-то особенно зловещее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А пробовали использовать `event.currentTarget` ? По хорошему разница между `target` и `currentTarget` описывается довольно просто.

`currentTarget` - общее понятие, и обычно им обозначается элемент, который находится "выше" всех по уровню иерархии. Т.е. если мы кликаем по какой либо кнопке на форме, то `currentTarget` будет указывать на форму т.к. кнопка "привязана" к форме (т.к. содержит кнопку внутри себя).

А вот `target` - это то, куда непосредственно направлен эвент. Т.е. с примером формы и кнопки, `target` будет указывать именно на кнопку.

Мне понравился вот этот пример [тык](http://jsfiddle.net/JoeQuery/ohng50st/). Надеюсь он достаточно нагляден, чтобы показать разницу.

Answer (score 1):

target - элемент который вызвал,
currentTarget - элемент инициатор события

а попробуйте в свиче прописать так
switch(event.target || event.srcElement).name){ ..